# If $2^{200} - 2^{192}\cdot31 + 2^n$ is a perfect square, find value(s) of $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question:** If $2^{200} - 2^{192}\cdot31 + 2^n$ is a perfect square, find value(s) of $n$.

My try is as follows:

For some number $m$ which belongs to $\mathbb{N}$:

$$2^n =  m^2 - 2^{192}\cdot225 = m^2 - (2^{96}\cdot15)^2 = (m - 2^{96}\cdot15)(m + 2^{96}\cdot15).$$

Now I can not understand that what should I do next in this problem.

Comment: Is it $\;192.31\;$ (decimal!) or $\;192\cdot31\;$ (product) in that power?

Comment: It was by mistake , now I have editted it.

Comment: @HarmanKing so it's supposed to be multiplied by $0.31$, not $31$?

Comment: It has to be multiplied with 31 but can you tell how to do the problem after this .

Comment: I don't understand this: how we had in the first line $\;2^{192}.31\;$ but then it appears as $\;2^{192}.225\;$ ?

Comment: $$m^2 =2^{192}.[2^{8}+1] + 2^{n} = 2^{192}.[225]+2^{n}$$ so after taking the value  $$2^{192}.[225]$$ on LHS we would get the above line which I have written.

Answer (score 1):

Given $$(x+y)(x-y)=2^n$$ then $x+y=2^p$ and $x-y=2^q$ with $p+q=n$

So $x=2^{p-1}+2^{q-1}$ and $y=2^{p-1}-2^{q-1}$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I have got it but after it I dont . Till here I had done it.

Comment: @HarmanKing:  It doesn't look like you have considered that both factors have to be powers of $2$.  That is Mark's point

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to collect 2^192, which is a square. The remaining expression in brackets becomes 2^8 - 31 + 2^(n - 192) = 225 + 2^(n - 192) , so that it remains to find the values of n for which  this quantity is a square. This is equivalent to determine a Pythagorean triple where one leg is 15 and where the other leg is a power of 2.
Based on the classical Diophantus formulas for the generation of PTs, it is easy to show that there are only 4 PTs with a leg equal to 15: two primitive (8, 15, 17 and 15, 112, 113), and two non-primitive (15, 20, 25 and 15, 36, 39). The only one where the other leg is a power of 2 is the first. Thus, we can set 2^(n - 192) = 8^2 = 2^6, which yields n = 198.